# Terraform cycle error with AWS API Gateway Rest API

Tags: rest, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

After upgrading from Terraform 0.13.5 to 1.3.3 I was forced to change my template*file resources into templatefile functions. This was due to my use of an ARM chip. I changed the aws api rest api resource to include the templatefile function in the body. Since making these changes I have encountered a series of "Error: Cycle:*..." failures. I have reworked the rest of my code to conform to the example shown on [the AWS provider examples](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_rest_api), this includes moving the stage name into its own resource, as well as removing any dependancies. Alas the changes proved to no avail. I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions to help resolve the cycle error.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "apigw" {
  name   = "standard-${var.environment_name}-${var.tenant_name}-isu-adapter"
  body   = templatefile("${path.module}/swagger.yaml",
    {
      apiTitle = "standard-${var.environment_name}-${var.tenant_name}-isu-adapter"
      # should correspond to aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.name!
      readLambdaUri = values(module.isu-adapter-read-lambda.lambda)[0].invoke_arn
    }
  )
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${var.central_account_id}:root"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "isu-adapter" {
  rest_api_id       = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.id
  triggers = {
    redeployment  = sha1(jsonencode(aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.body))
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "default_stage" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.isu-adapter.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.id
  stage_name    = "default"  
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "isu_stage" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.isu-adapter.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.id
  stage_name    = "${var.environment_name}-${var.tenant_name}"
  description   = format("%s/%s", md5(file("${path.module}/apigw.tf")), md5(file("${path.module}/swagger.yaml")))
  
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "read-lambda" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = values(module.isu-adapter-read-lambda.lambda)[0].function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

module "isu-adapter-read-lambda" {
  source                 = "../../../modules/lambda"
  environment_name       = var.environment_name
  lambda_name            = "isu-adapter-read"
  handler_name           = "read.handler"
  souce_path             = "adapters/lambda/"
  source_bucket          = var.source_bucket
  build_number           = var.build_number
  app_version            = var.app_version
  custom_role            = substr("standard-${var.environment_name}-isu-adapter-read-${var.tenant_name}-lambda", 0, 64)
  vpc_subnet_ids         = var.adapter_vpc_id == "" ? [] : var.adapter_subnet_ids
  vpc_security_group_ids = aws_security_group.isu-lambda-group.*.id
  timeout                = "180"
  tenants                = [
    {
      name   = var.tenant_name
      theme  = var.tenant_name
      domain = ""
    }
  ]

  environment_variables = [
    {
      STANDARD_BREAKER_TABLE_NAME                      = aws_dynamodb_table.circuit_breaker_state_table.name
      STANDARD_BREAKER_TABLE_KEY                       = var.tenant_name,
      STANDARD_CACHING_TABLE_NAME                      = aws_dynamodb_table.isu_adapter_caching_table.name
      STANDARD_ADAPTER_TYPE                            = var.adapter_type
      STANDARD_ADAPTER_PRIVATE_BUCKET_NAME             = var.adapter_private_bucket_enabled ? aws_s3_bucket.isu_adapter_private_bucket[0].bucket : ""
      STANDARD_ADAPTER_PRIVATE_BUCKET_ENABLED          = var.adapter_private_bucket_enabled
      STANDARD_TENANT_NAME                             = var.tenant_name
      STANDARD_ADAPTER_AUTH                            = var.use_adapter_auth_secret ? data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.auth-secret[0].secret_string : var.adapter_auth
      BASE_URL                                      = var.adapter_base_url
      STANDARD_ADAPTER_POSTBOX_READ_HISTORY_TABLE_NAME = aws_dynamodb_table.isu_adapter_postbox_read_history.name
      STANDARD_ADAPTER_POSTBOX_READ_HISTORY_QUEUE      = data.aws_sqs_queue.isu_adapter_postbox_read_history_queue.url
    }]
}

module "isu-adapter-write-lambda" {
  source                 = "../../../modules/lambda"
  environment_name       = var.environment_name
  lambda_name            = "isu-adapter-write"
  handler_name           = "write.handler"
  souce_path             = "adapters/lambda/"
  source_bucket          = var.source_bucket
  build_number           = var.build_number
  app_version            = var.app_version
  custom_role            = substr("standard-${var.environment_name}-isu-adapter-write-${var.tenant_name}-lambda", 0, 64)
  vpc_subnet_ids         = var.adapter_vpc_id == "" ? [] : var.adapter_subnet_ids
  vpc_security_group_ids = aws_security_group.isu-lambda-group.*.id
  tenants                = [
    {
      name   = var.tenant_name
      theme  = var.tenant_name
      domain = ""
    }
  ]
  environment_variables  = [
    {
      STANDARD_DEDUPLICATION_TABLE          = aws_dynamodb_table.write_deduplication_table.name
      STANDARD_BREAKER_TABLE_NAME           = aws_dynamodb_table.circuit_breaker_state_table.name
      STANDARD_BREAKER_TABLE_KEY            = var.tenant_name
      STANDARD_ADAPTER_TYPE                 = var.adapter_type
      STANDARD_ADAPTER_AUTH                 = var.use_adapter_auth_secret ? data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.auth-secret[0].secret_string : var.adapter_auth
      BASE_URL                           = var.adapter_base_url
      STANDARD_CACHING_TABLE_NAME           = aws_dynamodb_table.isu_adapter_caching_table.name
      STANDARD_ADAPTER_WRITE_FEEDBACK_QUEUE = data.aws_sqs_queue.write_feedback_queue.url
    }
  ]
}
```

```
Error: Cycle: aws_api_gateway_stage.default_stage, module.isu-adapter-read-lambda.null_resource.download[0], module.isu-adapter-read-lambda.aws_s3_bucket_object.lambda_source, aws_api_gateway_deployment.isu-adapter (destroy deposed d32dac59), module.isu-adapter-read-lambda.aws_s3_object.lambda_source (destroy), module.isu-adapter-read-lambda.aws_lambda_function.lambda["giessen"], module.isu-adapter-read-lambda.output.lambda (expand), aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw, aws_api_gateway_deployment.isu-adapter
```

**Steps Taken**
Update "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" body with templatefile swagger reference
Remove depends_on aws_api_gateway_rest_api from "aws_api_gateway_deploment"
Moved stage names to "aws_api_gateway_stage"

terraform init
terraform apply

Comment: I'm guessing something in the Lambda module is referencing the API Gateway.

Comment: Hello @MarkoE, you bring up a valid point. I am including the lambda modules referenced now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you had this previously working using a `data "template_file"` block then the most direct translation of that would be to swap the data resource for a [local value](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals) whose expression is a call to the `templatefile` function.

For example, if your original working configuration had a `data` block like this:

```
data "template_file" "swagger" {
  template = "${path.module}/swagger.yaml"
  vars = {
      apiTitle = "standard-${var.environment_name}-${var.tenant_name}-isu-adapter"
      # should correspond to aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.name!
      readLambdaUri = values(module.isu-adapter-read-lambda.lambda)[0].invoke_arn
  }
}
```

...then you can directly replace that with a local value like the following:

```
locals {
  swagger = templatefile("${path.module}/swagger.yaml", {
    apiTitle = "standard-${var.environment_name}-${var.tenant_name}-isu-adapter"
    # should correspond to aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.name!
    readLambdaUri = values(module.isu-adapter-read-lambda.lambda)[0].invoke_arn
  })
}
```

Anywhere you were previously referring to `data.template_file.swagger.rendered` you would refer to `local.swagger` instead, but otherwise leave the rest of the configuration unchanged.

This is different than what you've shown in your question because `local.swagger` remains as a separate node in the dependency graph. `local.swagger` has exactly the same dependencies and dependents as `data.template_file.swagger.rendered` had, and so this change should not affect the shape of the dependency graph at all.

In your case you wrote the `templatefile` call inline in the `resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "apigw"` block. It's valid to write `templatefile` calls inline like that in general, but notice that in this case it means that `aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw` now has a few extra direct dependencies that were previously only indirect dependencies:

- `module.isu-adapter-read-lambda.lambda`
- `var.environment_name`
- `var.tenant_name`

Adding new direct dependencies creates the opportunity for those new edges to create dependency cycles.

---

If this direct swap from a `data` block to a local value doesn't avoid the cycle problem then that would suggest that *something else* in your configuration has changed, aside from the removal of the `data "template_file"` block. I notice that your cycle message includes a `aws_api_gateway_deployment.isu-adapter (destroy deposed d32dac59)` entry, which suggests that a previous run of Terraform tried to replace this object but failed during the destroy step.

It may be better to resolve that situation first before changing your configuration any further, so that you won't have dangling unresolved actions in your state adding extra confusion to the process. However, resolving that situation would be quite a different question than what you asked here and so if you want to hear more about that then I'd suggest asking a new top-level question about it.

Comment: Hello Martin, your suggestion worked! Also in regards to the aws_api_gateway_deployment.isu-adapter (destroy deposed d32dac59) all that was needed was to terraform state rm and to reapply. Big thanks!